# How to run a local html file which is in my pc (Windows 7) to safari web browser on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, networking, web-applications, kendo-ui

I want to run my local html file which is saved on my desktop, on Safari of my iPhone. I have a local web server running on my system (xampp) as well as I have opened the ports(on which the file is running) required through my firewall. Is there any other settings I need to do on my iPhone also?

Please explain how to run the file. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your ISP provides a dynamic IP address you'll need to look into a service which overcomes this, for example [No IP](http://www.noip.com/). That way all you'll need to do is type in the domain provided to get to your web app.

Therefore, instead of accessing `http://123.123.123.123:8080` you simply run `http://your-new-domain.com:8080`.